# Web-scraping with R: how to perform the extraction of the same information from a list of links

Tags: r, list, web-scraping, data-science, rvest

#### Introduction and background

Hi! I hope you are all fine... My name is Bryan, I recentely graduated in Biochemical Engineering and I'm very interested in Data Science to apply it to my field. I had a course in undergrad on algorithms, and it made me passionate about programming. However, I didn't have time to try to deepen it. When the pandemic started, I decided to learn Python and took a Stanford course that they were offering for free. I learned a lot about the language, but when college classes started again, I was forced to put programming aside. About 15 days ago I decided to learn R. I thought there wouldn't be so many differences to Python, but I was surprised at how different they are...
To learn a little more about R for Data Science, I created a little project involving a subject I am passionate about (soccer). I know I skipped some steps in learning the language and, for this reason, I am already thinking about taking some classes specifically for R, about the syntax of the language, how it works, etc. (suggestions for courses and materials will be welcome too).

#### Idea

My idea is to extract some data from the Brazilian Championship (Serie A) in the era of points scored (2003-2021) on the [besoccer](https://besoccer.com) site.

#### Tools used

- R language
- Rstudio
- robotstxt", "rvest", "dplyr", "writexl" libraries
- Extension "SelectorGadget" for Google Chrome

#### Code

```r
# Importing libraries
library("robotstxt")
library("rvest")
library("dplyr")
library("writexl")

# Verifying if besoccer accepts automated extraction
links <- c("https://www.besoccer.com/", "https://www.besoccer.com/competition/scores/serie_a_brazil/NNN")

paths_allowed(links)

# Pages and HTML extraction
years <- 2003:2021
br_links <- paste("https://www.besoccer.com/competition/scores/serie_a_brazil/",
                  years, sep = "")

htmls <- br_links %>%
  lapply(read_html)

# Getting informations (sample)  
for (html in htmls) {
  matches <- htmls %>%
    html_nodes("#mod_competition_season .item-col:nth-child(1) .main-line") %>%
    html_text()
  total_matches <- as.numeric(matches)
}
```

#### Explaining the code

1. I used the "robotstxt" library to check if the site accepts data extraction. I took a look at the HTML of the page and verified that the "NNN" is replaced by the year of the competition. So, I concluded that, if it passed the test, there would be no problem extracting data from the pages of the championships from 2003 to 2021.
2. As I said before, I noticed that the championship url was always the same, only changing the year at the end. To facilitate the access to the pages, I created a vector with the years (2003 through 2021) and created an object to store the links of the 19 competitions that I obtained using the "paste" function, in which I used the "prefix" of the page and the vector with the years. The result is a character object with 19 entries (one for each championship year).
3. I used the function "read_html" from the package "rvest" to get the HTML of the pages. Since I had an array of character type, I chose to use the function "lapply" to iterate over the array and extract the HTML. The result is a list with the HTML of the 19 pages of the competition.
4. Finally, I bring an example of information that I want to extract (number of championship matches). For this, I used the "html_nodes" function from the "rvest" package to point to which CSS selector I want. I used the Chrome extension to get the exact selector. Then, I used the "html_text" function from the "rvest" package to transform the information into text, and finally convert it to numeric information for later compute (since you don't do calculation with strings/texts). I used a repetition loop to iterate through all the pages.

#### The Problem

After performing what I explained in step 4 above, I got the following error:

> **Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "list"**.

My interpretation of the error is that the method of the function is not applicable for a list, and then my head bugged, because I tried to undo the list by applying the indexes in the loop and was not successful. I believe there is some problem with my logic in the problem, but unfortunately I am not able to find the error myself.
**Side note:** I tested what was inside the for loop on just one page (2003 Championship) to see if what I wrote in the "matches" object would run if it was on just one HTML (without for loop), and not on a list of HTML's... and the answer is that it did!

#### Questions

My questions are: how can I extract the same information from all 19 pages, since the selector is the same on all pages? What is wrong with my loop? If someone can point me to the error, the solution and explain it to me, I'd really appreciate it! See you later! o/

Comment: So you want to extract **Matches played** ?

Comment: Yep, this is one information that I want to extract from every page...

Answer (score 0):

We can use JS path `#mod_competition_season > div > div.panel-body.item-column-list > div:nth-child(1) > div.main-line` to get number of matches played.

- JS path helps in locating a particular object located in webpage like in which class or node is it in.
- `function(x)` indicates tells `lapply` to loop the defined function.

  ```
   lapply(br_links, function(x) {
      x %>% read_html()%>% 
        html_nodes('#mod_competition_season > div > div.panel-body.item-column-list > div:nth-child(1) > div.main-line') %>% html_text()
    })
  ```

Comment: Tks for your answer, Nad! Could you explain the code to me, please? I never saw that "function(x)" thing... And how JS path works? Again, thank you!

Comment: Added a simple explanation hope it helps.